# Can't use DB::query in laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I get this error when I use

```
DB::query : "SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES)".
```

But the username I set in configs/database.php is not homestead at all. Someone knows what could be the problem?

Comment: Check the database connection configuration.

Comment: I've checked, and there's no homestead user in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are using laravel 5,in laravel  5 they have changed structure you have to edit configuration file **.env** in root folder that will do it...